# Matching all non-punctuation, non-special characters and support multilingual characters

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

I want to match all characters across multiple languages except ones that would not be appropriate in the *name* or *title* of something, such as special characters, punctuation, and non-printable characters. I want to allow underscore '_' and numbers, but I also do not want the string to start with a underscore. Also the string should no longer than 100 characters, and must not be empty.

Basically I want to form a multilingual version of the following regex: `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,99 }`

Minimally, this needs to work on server-side validation done in an ASP.NET MVC application. Optimally it could also work in JavaScript for client-side validation, but I wouldn't mind it failing on the server with a slightly weaker regular expression that blacklisted some symbols and punctuation but might let one or two characters through and ultimately failing on the server.

Based on what I've found searching, I have tried something like:
 `[^\p{L}\p{N} ]+` but that seems to match punctuation too. I have also tried `[\p{Xan}]`.

Now, I realize I'm testing these on a website called [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com) and the reason these might be working is the fact that Unicode support in regular expressions in JavaScript seems to be limited. Could it just "not work" when I'm testing it in debuggex but will work perfectly fine in the actual application?

Comment: Why not test it in the actual application?

Comment: Part of the reason is I do not have an actual application yet. This is actually for a requirements document. I don't want to be stuck with figuring out a complex regex if I can just change the requirements document to be "will only accept non-accented English characters, numbers, and an underscore"

Comment: You are right. Javascript regex has limited support for unicode. It doesn't recognize \p{}. You should use a regex tester that uses .net's regex class instead like http://regexhero.net/tester/.

Comment: If it is based on what you think you can produce then it is a functional design not a requirements document.